# Sql output in certain pattern for each visit

Tags: sql-server-2012

We have a MS SQL Server 2012 and I need help with figuring out certain pattern output using SQL query. First field on Result below needs to be hard coded letters. D stands for demographic, R for revenue, and P for Design. Here is the sqlfiddle sample of the schema: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bed148/1

Expected Result:

```
D   ID101   James   
R   ID101   $10     
P   ID101   1001    
D   ID102   Rock    
R   ID102   $50     
P   ID102   1002    
D   ID103   Paul    
R   ID103   $30     
P   ID103   1003
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
Select 'D' as i, PersonID, name from Demographics
union
Select 'R' as i, PersonID, Payment from Revenue
union
Select 'P' as i, PersonID, Item from Design
order by PersonId, i
```

Comment: Probably with `ORDER BY`

Comment: Ahmed Ashour - Thanks! Can't believe it was that simple. Surprised.

Answer (score 1):

With CTE,

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bed148/4/3

```
with t(Indicator, PersonID, Value)
as
(
  select 'D', * from Demographics
  union
  select 'R', * from Revenue
  union
  select 'P', * from Design
)
select Indicator, PersonID, Value
from t
order by 2, 1
```